# Emberjs only rerender component after observer in view is triggered

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to display errors next to a form's input. In its current incarnation, it rerenders the page whenever the fooErrors property in the controller changes. However, it rerenders the entire view, which messes up the heading in the view. Is there a way I could only rerender the part of the view that contains the component?

The code:

app/views/foo/form.js:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  errorsChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('controller.fooErrors')
});
```

app/controllers/foo/edit.js:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin,{
  fooErrors: false,
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      var _this = this;
      var foo = this.get('content');
      foo.validate().finally(function() {
        // form is submitted
        } else {
          foo.set('hasErrors', true);
          _this.set('fooErrors', true);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

app/models/foo.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
  hasErrors: false
}
```

`app/foo/form.hbs`:

```
<h1>{{fooId}}</h1>
<form>
{{input type="text" placeholder="foo id" valueBinding="fooId"}}{{form-error errors=fooErrors foo=model field="fooId"}}
<button {{action 'submit'}}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

app/templates/components/form-error.hbs:

```
{{#if errors}}
  <span>{{error}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

app/components/form-error.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['error'],
  error: function() {
    var risk = this.risk,
        field = this.field;

    if (risk.get('hasErrors')) {
      return risk.get('errors').get(field);
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }.property()
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to rerender that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the OP design, a simple approach to refresh only the component is by getting it from the view and calling rerender on that. To get the component from the view just add a `viewName`.

For example,

**hbs**

```
....{{form-error errors=fooErrors foo=model field="fooId" viewName="theErrorsCmp"}}
```

**js**

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  errorsChanged: function() {
//if this fires for some reason at the very beginning before the view has been inserted to the DOM and the component is not yet available then just check before using it, i.e. uncomment the following line
//if(!Em.isEmpty(this.get("theErrorsCmp")))
    this.get("theErrorsCmp").rerender();
  }.observes('controller.fooErrors')
});
```